# trouble with installing epdfree

Tags: python, enthought

I am trying to install epdfree on two virtually identical machines: Linux 2.6.18-308.1.1.el5, CentOS release 5.8., 64-bit machines.  (BTW, I'm a bit new to python.)

After the install on one machine, I run python and try to import scipy.  Everything goes fine.

On the other machine, I follow all the same steps as far as I can tell, but when I try to import scipy, I am told “ImportError: No module named scipy”.

As far as I can tell, I am doing *everything* the same on the two machines.  I installed from the same script, I run the python in the epdfree installation directory, everything I can think of.

Does anyone have any idea what would keep “import scipy” from working on one machine while it works fine on the other?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out there was one difference.  File permissions were being set differently on the two machines.  I installed epdfree as su on both machines.  On the second machine, everything was locked out when I tried to run it without going under "su".  Now my next task is to find out why the permissions were set differently.  I guess it's a difference in umask settings?  Well, this I won't bother anyone with.  But feel free to offer an answer if you want to!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have  the library scipy installed, which is a totally different library of epdfree.

you can install it from apt-get in linux I guess, or going to their website
www.scipy.org